# WPF Drawing Colored Grid Lines on a Canvas Panel Background

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, background

Similar to the look of graph paper, I want to draw straight lines of different colors on the Background of a Canvas to form a grid. The following code works fine for drawing only red lines. I also want to draw some Blue lines and gray lines. That means I need two more sets of lines, and so far I've not been able to solve the issue of drawing new sets of lines of additional colors.

```
<Window x:Class="GridTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000">

<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Canvas Width="10000" Height="10000">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
                          Viewport="0,0 100,100" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryGroup>
                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,100"/>
                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="100,0"/>
                            </GeometryGroup>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Red"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

To reiterate...this code is doing what I want for single color. But I also want to add lines of different colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add multiple canvases to the root canvas, each with its own background pen:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Canvas Width="10000" Height="10000">
        <Canvas  Width="10000" Height="10000">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
                          Viewport="0,0 10,10" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryGroup>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,10"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="10,0"/>
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="DarkGray"/>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas  Width="10000" Height="10000">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
                          Viewport="0,0 50,50" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryGroup>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,50"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="50,0"/>
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Blue"/>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas  Width="10000" Height="10000">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
                          Viewport="0,0 100,100" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryGroup>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,100"/>
                                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="100,0"/>
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Red"/>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Alternatively, you could use [`VisualBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which constructs a brush out of any `UIElement`.  So you could make the canvas background out of a `Grid` with `Rectangles` inside, or any similar approach:

```
<Canvas> 
    <Canvas.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Width="10000" Height="10000">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
                                Viewport="0,0 10,10" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryGroup>
                                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,10"/>
                                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="10,0"/>
                                            </GeometryGroup>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                            <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="DarkGray"/>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle Width="10000" Height="10000">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
                                Viewport="0,0 50,50" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryGroup>
                                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,50"/>
                                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="50,0"/>
                                            </GeometryGroup>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                            <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Blue"/>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle Width="10000" Height="10000">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile"
                                Viewport="0,0 100,100" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryGroup>
                                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,100"/>
                                                <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="100,0"/>
                                            </GeometryGroup>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                            <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Red"/>
                                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    </GeometryDrawing>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks again...I tested the first option and it works like a champ. I think the first option is the one I will go with.